# How to modify custom.css styling on Docusaurus items

Tags: docusaurus

I am looking for the syntax needed to reference an item in Docusaurus allowing me to modify the background color/text color of a collapsed item.

Example image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIkrb.png)

How exactly can I reference docusaurus code to modify the coloring of these bubbles?

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear what exactly you are asking.

You can find how to add styling and layout here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout

You can create custom react components and add them to the documentation to completely customise the html element. Alternatively you could inspect the element to find the class used by docusaurus to change the css of the elements you want.